# C# powershell objects as a datasource

Tags: c#, powershell, objectdatasource, psobject

Bare bones of the problem: 
I am trying to populate a ComboBox, or even a ListBox for Windows Forms and for standard arrays and class definitions, it works great using DataSources and the related ValueMember and DisplayMember.

The problem arises when I attempt to utilise a returned Collection of PSObjects (powershell objects).

Here is the code section that I have tried:

```
private void PopulateGroups()
{
    // DistributionGroups is a Collection<PSObject>
    DistributionGroups.Clear();
    DistributionGroups = GroupADConnection.GroupsInOU("OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Resources,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=MadeUp");

    cmbDistributionGroups.DataSource = DistributionGroups;

    string test = DistributionGroups[5].Members["DistinguishedName"].Value.ToString();

    cmbDistributionGroups.DisplayMember = @"Members[""SamAccountName""].Value.ToString()";
    cmbDistributionGroups.ValueMember = "Members[\"DistinguishedName\"].Value.ToString()";
}
```

Basic background is that `DistributionGroups` is a `Collection<PSObject>` which has the members `DistinguishedName` and `SamAccountName`.

With the code displayed here, the `DisplayMember` will show the whole PSObject value through the ToString method, giving me: `@{SamAccountName=AA_ Officer; DistinguishedName=CN=AA\+ Officer,OU=Administration,OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Resources,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=MadeUp}`

I have tried both methods of getting a quote character into the string so it will get the correct property. The `test` String object will correctly get the required member of the PSObject.

Is there something I am missing or is there no way to effectively do this without self defining an array with the PSObject members individually transferred?

Update:
After some more testing, it seems that the DataSource, more specifically the Value/Display Members only take the LAST argument. As in for the given: `"Members[\"DistinguishedName\"].Value.ToString()"` it only actually uses the `ToString()` part.

Is this the intended behaviour of the Value/Display Member attributes? Is there a way for me to make it use the full definition?

Comment: I'm curious why you're using PowerShell-in-C# to do this instead of using `System.DirectoryServices` directly.

Comment: Inherited alot of powershell scripts and am attempting to utilise these before going out and starting fresh. The scripts work ok but are hard to explain to less technical people. In the end I may have to rewrite, but would really prefer not to mess with a working script.